# Changing App.css in create-react-app not affecting page

Tags: css, reactjs

My index.js for React, I used a create-react-app starter project.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from './App';

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

My app.js includes:

import './App.css';

and I use the CSS:

```
.body {
  background-color: "green"
}
```

and the body does not change to green.

How do I modify CSS? I also tried placing app.css into public/app.css and loading with link rel="stylesheet" Element inspector still showed no effect.

Element inspector shows margin of 8px on body element from "user agent stylesheet".. nothing from my loaded css.

EDIT:

I also try inline style tag:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<script src="web3.js"></script>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico">
    <title>CryptoClicker</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>

  </body>
  <style>
  .body {
    background: "green";
  }
  </style>
</html>
```

no effect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `.body` which is looking for elements with the class 'body' - as there's a `.` Change that to `body` (with no `.`) and it'll style the body element rather than the class.

Also, named colours in CSS are not variable strings - so remove the quotes:

```
body {
  background: green;
}
```

It'd be worth putting your styles back into App.css and importing it in JS rather than using the `<style>` tags.

Comment: Thank you - I switched back to App.css. Removing the . answers the question! How can I reference by #? I tried background: "#AABBCC"

Comment: Again, remove the quotes - `background: #aabbcc` is fine. You pretty much never need quotes for anything native to CSS.

Comment: I did not expect that. Thank you for the clarification